# Git Submodules And Deploying To Production

Tags: git, continuous-integration, git-submodules, gerrit

We are splitting up a project into 2 parts.  One of the parts will be basically the core library for the software, and we were thinking to make it a submodule.

When we created the submodule on the dev machine we untracked the code, deleted and added the repo as a submodule to where the code existed before the delete.

Now is where I think we've run into our problem.

Git created .gitmodules which references our Gerrit server username@server:repo.git so this can't be tracked since other users don't share my same username.

The only way I can see is to not track it.  Deploy the branch.  Go to production and add the submodule like on the dev server.

Is that the right workflow or is there a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

You would typically add the submodule using an anonymous mechanism, such as a `git://` or unauthenticated `http://` URL.

If you need to make commits to the submodule, you would either add a second remote using `git remote add` or just checkout out another copy of the module somewhere else for editing.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use secure login with the submodule.  Remove your username from the URL in .gitmodules, and have all users configure their machines to specify the username when hitting your server.  This can be done with the `.netrc` file if using https, or with the `.ssh/config` file if using ssh.

Here is an example ssh config:

```
Host my-corp-server.corp.com
    User my-username
```

This is the method we use for dealing with submodules at $DAYJOB and it works fine.